# Zendesk API: How do I get the number of tickets for each view based on brand?

Tags: php, zendesk, zendesk-api

I'm using the Zendesk API with PHP and trying to get the number of tickets with a specific brand for each view. 
The only solution i've come up with is get all the views, load all the tickets in that view, get the brand for each ticket.
There has to be a more optimal solution than this. 
Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Have you tried to create a new view that shows the tickets for a given brand? You should be able to then call that view using the API in order to get your desired results if I'm understanding your question right.

Answer (score 1):

Best I could think of was to authenticate with a user account that has only access to tickets with that particular brand, and then use the [View Counts API](https://developer.zendesk.com/rest_api/docs/core/views#view-counts) to count the total tickets in each View (which would exclude getting info of tickets that the user cannot view).

So you would be making a call to several views with one API like such:

```
https://subdomainname.zendesk.com/api/v2/views/count_many.json?ids=VIEW_ID_1,VIEW_ID_2,VIEW_ID_3,VIEW_ID_4
```

and the response will come back as an array of **view_counts**, which each holds a "value" attribute - the number of tickets found for that view.

There's a note above that document for View Counts though, explaining about the "value" attribute. It states:

> The cached number of tickets in the view. Can also be null if the
>   system is loading and caching new data. Not to be confused with 0
>   tickets

which is pretty annoying because I found myself suddenly getting **null** for some values, and it was quite confusing.

Answer (score 0):

```
https://subdomain.zendesk.com/api/v2/views/{id}/count.json
```

this will returns the ticket count for a single view and the response will

```
 {
  "view_count": {
    "view_id": 25,
    "url":     "https://company.zendesk.com/api/v2/views/25/count.json",
    "value":   719,
    "pretty":  "~700",
    "fresh":   true
  }
}
```

if you want to try with multiple ids, use

```
https://subdomain.zendesk.com/api/v2/views/count_many.json?ids={view_id},{view_id}
```

Calculates the size of the view in terms of number of tickets the view will return. Only returns values for personal and shared views accessible to the user performing the request.